# decodeFile returns null where is the mistake

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        path="file:///storage/emulated/0/1/138242/2019-07-03114920.jpg"
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

BitmapFactory.decodeFile return null

Comment: did you put required permission in manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
this permission?

Comment: this one `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: this permission is also there

Comment: put your code in `try catch` and check the log for any error. also try your code with smaller/other  image

Comment: resizing the image did not help, put this code in a try catch also no error. 
Maybe the way to the image is not so imagine?

Comment: search this : `BitmapFactory.decodeFile return null` check others problem may help you